# Solving first degree linear equations in R

Tags: r

I am new at R and I am trying to do a function to resolve first degree linear equations but I don't know how to start. For example, given a function like:

7x+4 = 18 or 5x+3=0

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: The way to solve it for computers is using linear algebra. See this guide: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matlib/vignettes/linear-equations.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I do a base R solution:

```
sol = function(A,B,C){
    C-B
    -B/A
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do solve linear equations (and loads of more complicated symbolic calculation tasks) using the library `Ryacas`.

Example:

```
require(Ryacas)

yacas('Solve(7*x + 4 == 18, x)')
Yacas vector:
[1] x == 2
```

For a more thorough discussion, see
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ryacas0/vignettes/elaborate-reference.html, and https://www.brodrigues.co/blog/2013-12-31-r-cas/.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution:

```
> uniroot(function(x) 7*x + 4 - 18, c(0, 5))$root
[1] 2
> uniroot(function(x) 5*x + 3, c(-3, 0))$root
[1] -0.6
>
```

Rewrite your equations, if necessary, in the form `f(x) = 0` (as in the first example).  The second parameter gives the range over which to search for a solution.